# SSO between Sharepoint & Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, single-sign-on

I have a Sharepoint Site(am not the SP expert) where user logs in this is form based authentication model where Username password is stored in a db...now when user clicks on a link i want him to redirect to a MVC3 application. While doing so i want user tobe autmatically signed in to MVC application. What is the best way to implement that.

Thanks

Comment: Where is this MVC application located? (On the same server, on a different domain etc?)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass authentication token in the http header from SharePoint to other web application. Then, MVC application should validate the token before accessing the web site.